# New Parse UI login view customatization

Tags: parse-platform

i am trying to customize the new log in view from parse UI

```
[self.logInView.facebookButton setTitle:@"Vpiši se z Facebook računom" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.logInView.facebookButton setTitle:@"Vpiši se z Facebook računom" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.logInView.logInButton setTitle:@"Prijavi se" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.logInView.logInButton setTitle:@"Prijavi se" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.logInView.signUpButton setTitle:@"Registracija" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.logInView.signUpButton setTitle:@"Registracija" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

as i believe this code should change the facebookButton label, logInButton label and signUpButton label. But sadly it only sucessefully changes the logInButton label and the other two remain the same. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Here is the entire class:

.h file

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>

@interface MyLogInViewController : PFLogInViewController

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "MyLogInViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface MyLogInViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *fieldsBackground;
@end

@implementation MyLogInViewController

@synthesize fieldsBackground;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //[self.logInView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.logInView setLogo:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PrehranaLogo"]]];

    self.logInView.usernameField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Uporabniško ime" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]}];
self.logInView.passwordField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Geslo" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]}];

[self.logInView.passwordForgottenButton setTitle:@"Ste pozabili geslo?" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.logInView.passwordForgottenButton setTitle:@"Ste pozabili geslo?" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.logInView.facebookButton setTitle:@"Vpiši se z Facebook računom" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.logInView.facebookButton setTitle:@"Vpiši se z Facebook računom" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.logInView.logInButton setTitle:@"Prijavi se" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.logInView.logInButton setTitle:@"Prijavi se" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.logInView.signUpButton setTitle:@"Registracija" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.logInView.signUpButton setTitle:@"Registracija" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: I suggest you post the complete class. Did you (for instance) inherit properly??? We can't see... so show us! :)

Comment: Should i report bug?

Comment: I suggest you look at the tutorial and sample (Including the code)   https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you shouldn't change objects, you should add localization for Slovenian language.

Quoting parse.com documentation:
The easiest way to customize a string is through the default localization support provided by iOS.

https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

Hope it helps.